# systick example on cortex m3 not working

Tags: c, arm, cortex-m

I am trying to measure the time elapsed during a function but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. When I stop the systick its value returned is 24 which is not possible.

```
#define SYSTICKS 0xFFFFFFu
static volatile  uint32_t Count = 0;

void SysTick_Handler(void)
{
    Count++;
}

int doSomething()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 8;

    return a + b;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])

    SysTick_Config(SYSTICKS);

    volatile uint64_t a = (uint64_t)SYSTICKS - SysTick->VAL;
    a += ((uint64_t)SYSTICKS * Count);

    /* some code here */
    doSomething();

    volatile uint64_t b = (uint64_t)SYSTICKS - SysTick->VAL;
    b += ((uint64_t)SYSTICKS * Count);

    volatile uint64_t timeElapsed = a - b;
    printf("a = %lld\r\n", a);
    printf("b = %lld\r\n", b);
    printf("timeElapsed = %lld\n", timeElapsed);
```

And here is the output

```
a = 16777215
b = 24
timeElapsed = 16777191
```

Comment: "I am trying to measure the time elapsed during a function" - Many CM3/4/7 support the Debug cycle countr registers. Why not use them? The systick timer is not well suited for this anyway.

Comment: @Olaf I have tried those debug cycle registers also but has not worked for me. There is no mention of these registers in the datasheet for my m3 so I'm thinking they are not supported

Comment: the m3 has a systick timer.  back up and try this, do your init, go into an infinite loop where you read the raw systick timer value and print it out.  Does it change?  If not please show your systick init.

Comment: note that your code under test is dead code and as a result should be optimized out completely by the compiler (it should take no time as there is no code to execute there).

Comment: Which device is it exactly? The STM32 all have this module. You should get the Architecture Refderence Manual from ARM. MCU vendors only provide their device-specific confuguration; information about CPU and other IP cores from ARM are generic. What do you mean with "I tried those"? Either you are awre they exist or not. And did you enable the counter?

Comment: the overhead as to how you use the systick timer, will take time, and the relationship between your flash speed and fetching vs system clock may account for the time, 24 counts does seem very high.  if you didnt optimize then perhaps it is on par.  using 64 bit variables for a 24 bit timer is also going to burn extra time.

Comment: @old_timer: OP already usese SysTick and initialises it. But without details, it is impossible to tell.

Comment: just checked the cortex-m3 does have a systick timer, it is not documented as being optional (like other cores directly state).  Granted the m3 was the first one out to the general public and perhaps the documentation didnt include that

Comment: please show disassembly of code under test including the reading of the timer

Comment: Why do you use 64 bit variables and why `volatile`? That's superflous. SysTick is a 24 bit counter! And `a - b` … think yourself: which one is supposed to be the higher value?

Comment: Note subtracting from the max count makes no sense (or is unnecessary overhead, have to think about it), read before, read after, this is a down counter, subtract before from after, and with 0xFFFFFF and that is your delta assuming you have set the timer to wrap around as a continuous timer (reload is 0xFFFFFF and you allow it to wrap).

Comment: systick handler!  you have not enabled interrupts have you for the timer?

Comment: please go back to the basics of initializing the timer, and an infinite loop that just prints the current value forever, watch it count down and roll around and make sure no interrupts happen, etc.  THEN you can try to use it to time things.

Comment: also note there is a LOT more to learn if you are trying to time code execution on a microcontroller like this.  the systick timer works just fine for this, but alignment, flash wait states, flash vs sram, etc are all going to play a role.  and the results will mostly be specific to this chip and not necessarily translate to other chips from the same vendor or with the same core.

Comment: @old_timer I ran an infinite loop printing systick value and it counts down and rolls around.

Comment: so if you do two reads, and subtract the second from the first, print out all three values what do you get?

Comment: a = SysTick->VAL; b=SysTick->VAL; c=(a-b)&0xFFFFFF;  all 32 bit uint variables.

Comment: what is your prescaler set to?

Comment: @old_timer I done this:   `SysTick_Config(SYSTICKS);`                                
    `uint32_t a = SysTick->VAL;`
    `uint32_t b = SysTick->VAL;`
    `uint32_t c = (a - b) & ADI_CYCLE_COUNTING_SYSTICKS;`
    `PRINT_MESSAGE("a = %ld\tb = %ld\tc = (a-b) & 0xFFFFFFFF = %ld\r\n",a, b, c);` and the output was `a = 0 b = 16777214 c = (a-b) & 0xFFFFFFFF = 2`

Comment: looks about right

Comment: now you can try to put some code in the middle.  your specific code under test is dead code and if you use an optimizer will go away (check the disassembly to see what I am talking about).

Comment: @old_timer thanks very much so I ran a loop of 100 no_ops and the result of the output is `start = 0 end = 16776706 elapsed = (o - 16776706) & 0xFFFFFFFF = 510` just to confirm everything is ok is this about right

Comment: too many bits in your mask, use 0x00FFFFFF not 0xFFFFFFFF it is a 24 bit timer not 32.  this covers the case when you time something when it is rolling over, if the thing being timed takes more than one whole rollover period then you need to use a prescaler or deal with the rollover in some other way.  will let you do the math to figure out at your clock rate how long a rollover is...